# Shortcut menu not showing after admin menu installed

Tags: 7

I have installed the admin menu module and now the shortcuts menu has disappeared. 
This is quite confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar is the core drupal module which  displays the shortcuts near the top of the page, along with an Edit shortcuts link. After installing admin-menu we do not need core toolbar module otherwise it causes redundancy for admin menu,uninstalling the toolbar module causes vanish of shortcut bar with it.

Shortcut bar comes from shortcut module, which simply allows us to place the shortcut block by going to (Administer > Structure > Blocks) and look for Shotcut block which by default goes under disabled block.